# Outbound IIS Rewrite Rule not adding Parameter, what am I missing?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I want to use IIS Rewrite to change /blog.aspx?Page=2 to /blog?Page=2 but as its the address is in a DataPager, its not so simple.  TO get round this, I've come up with the following IIS rewrite rule.

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="BlogArticlesOutbound" stopProcessing="true">
        <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^/blog.aspx\?page=([0-9]+)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="/blog?page={R1}" />
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

However, the output is missing the page number, what do I need to do to change it to get it to work?  My style sheet seems to also disappear from the page when i use the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your back-reference syntax is a tiny bit wrong. You should use it as `{R:1}`.

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="BlogArticlesOutbound" stopProcessing="true">
        <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^/blog.aspx\?page=([0-9]+)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="/blog?page={R:1}" />
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

Comment: Thanks Vape, the phrase 'Can't see the wood for the trees' is very appropriate here.  Thanks for spotting this.